# Why can't I use same variable in switch?

Tags: java

For example, if I write code like this:

```
    double result = 0;
    switch (operation) {
        case "divide":
            double result = (double) first / second;
            string = Double.toString(result);
            break;
        case "multiply":
            double result = (double) first * second;
            string = Double.toString(result);
            break;
        case "substract":
            double result = (double) first - second;
            string = Double.toString(result);
            break;
        case "add":
            double result = (double) first + second;
            string = Double.toString(result);
            break;
    }
```

It returns error: Variable 'result' is already defined in the scope.

I know how to work around this. I could make a different variable in each case, but that would then prolong code by having to write code for each variable.

How to make this work as written in the code given?

Comment: you could wrap each case in brackets like `case "divide": { ... }` and so on to give each case its own scope

Comment: I just tried doing that, but it doesn't fix it. It still reports the same error.

Comment: http://ideone.com/L2wu9I

Comment: its bcoz u have declared it twice just remove this `double result = 0;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is being caused by the fact that `result` is already defined at the top of the `switch` statement, and you are declaring it again in your statement.

Try something like this:

```
switch (operation) {
    case "divide":
        double result = (double) first / second;
        string = Double.toString(result);
        break;
    case "multiply":
        double result = (double) first * second;
        string = Double.toString(result);
        break;
    case "substract":
        double result = (double) first - second;
        string = Double.toString(result);
        break;
    case "add":
        double result = (double) first + second;
        string = Double.toString(result);
        break;
}
```

In other words, what you had before, except from your initial declaration.

---

Alternatively, you could declare the `double` and use it in each of your cases:

```
double result = 0;
switch (operation) {
    case "divide":
        result = (double) first / second;
        string = Double.toString(result);
        break;

    ...
```

---

As *Yassin Hajaj* pointed out in the comments, it would be much better if you used the `string = Double.toString(result);` line *once* at the end of your `switch` statement, instead of repeating it multiple times.

That would look something like this:

```
double result = 0;
switch (operation) {
    case "divide":
        result = (double) first / second;
        break;
    case "multiply":
        result = (double) first * second;
        break;
    ...
}
string = Double.toString(result);
```

Comment: Ohh. I was initialising result again in case statments. Done as you said and it Works now, Thank you very much.

Comment: @Leonz Glad I could help! :)

Comment: @Leonz Please optimize the code. You may write `string = Double.toString(result)` once outside of the switch instead of writing it 4 times.

Comment: Thanks @YassinHajaj for pointing that out. I've updated my answer to include this.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot declare same variable name in one scope in your code you use global result variable and also you use same variable in case scope.

```
double result = 0;
    switch (operation) {
        case "divide":
            result = (double) first / second;
            string = Double.toString(result);
            break;
        case "multiply":
            result = (double) first * second;
            string = Double.toString(result);
            break;
        case "substract":
            result = (double) first - second;
            string = Double.toString(result);
            break;
        case "add":
            result = (double) first + second;
            string = Double.toString(result);
            break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually can by using brackets.

```
    switch (operation) {
        case "divide": {
            double result = (double) first / second;
            string = Double.toString(result1);
            break;
        }
        case "multiply": {
            double result = (double) first * second;
            string = Double.toString(result2);
            break;
        }
        default: 
            break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In java any local variable defined within {} are available till the last line, so you can reuse any where after defining within block. So in your case no use to redefine the result variable. Just define in the first row and use everywhere.

```
double result = 0;
    switch (operation) {
        case "divide":
            result = (double) first / second;
            string = Double.toString(result1);
            break;
        case "multiply":
            result = (double) first * second;
            string = Double.toString(result2);
            break;
        case "substract":
            result = (double) first - second;
            string = Double.toString(result3);
            break;
        case "add":
            result = (double) first + second;
            string = Double.toString(result4);
            break;
    }
```

Comment: ... you can go even further ... and move  `string = Double.toString(result);` outside the switch ...

Answer (score 0):

becaue you are already define double result variable so do it like below hope it will work

```
double result = 0; <----- already define here
switch (operation) {
    case "divide":
        result = (double) first / second;  <------  there is no need to 
                                                    define it again
        string = Double.toString(result1);
        break;
    case "multiply":
        result = (double) first * second;
        string = Double.toString(result2);
        break;
    case "substract":
        result = (double) first - second;
        string = Double.toString(result3);
        break;
    case "add":
        result = (double) first + second;
        string = Double.toString(result4);
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a common variable then you can do like this.

```
double result = 0;
    switch (operation) {
        case "divide":
            result = (double) first / second;
            string = Double.toString(result);
            break;
        case "multiply":
            result = (double) first * second;
            string = Double.toString(result);
            break;
        case "substract":
            result = (double) first - second;
            string = Double.toString(result);
            break;
        case "add":
            result = (double) first + second;
            string = Double.toString(result);
            break;
    }
```